# How to Mount NFS Root in Maverick

Tags: 10.10, filesystem, nfs, pxe

After upgrading to 10.10 Maverick, my NFS root is not mounted correctly during boot. What is the correct method?

10.04 and earlier I had my `/etc/fstab` setup to use `/dev/nfs` as my root device, but it looks like that no longer exists. Is anyone else using 10.10 for NFS boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the fstab format changed slightly. The following is a working line for the root partition:

```
192.168.0.1:/nfs-root   /   nfs    rw,noatime,nolock,vers=3   0   0
```